# Preserve dataframe partitioning when writing and re-reading to parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

When I write a dataframe with a defined partitioning to disk as parquet file and then re-read the parquet file again, the partitioning is lost. Is there a way to preserve the original partitioning of the dataframe during writing and re-reading?

The example code

```scala
//create a dataframe with 100 partitions and print the number of partitions
val originalDf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10000).toDF().repartition(100)
println("partitions before writing to disk: " + originalDf.rdd.partitions.length)

//write the dataframe to a parquet file and count the number of files actually written to disk
originalDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("tmp/testds")
println("files written to disk: " + new File("tmp/testds").list.size)

//re-read the parquet file into a dataframe and print the number of partitions 
val readDf = spark.read.parquet("tmp/testds")
println("partitions after reading from disk: " + readDf.rdd.partitions.length)
```

prints out

```
partitions before writing to disk: 100
files written to disk: 202
partitions after reading from disk: 4
```

Observations:

- The first number is the expected result, the dataframe consists of 100 partitions
- The second number also looks good to me: I get 100 `*.parquet` files, 100 `*.parquet.crc`  files and two `_SUCCESS` files, so the parquet file still consists of 100 partitions
- The third line shows that after reading the parquet file again the original partitioning is lost and the amount of partitions after reading the parquet file is changed. The number of partitions is related to the number of executors of my Spark cluster
- The results are the same no matter if I write the parquet file to a local disk or a Hdfs store
- When I run an action on `readDf` I can see in the SparkUI that four tasks are created, when calling `foreachPartition` on `readDf` the function is executed four times

Is there a way to preserve the original partitioning of the dataframe without calling `repartition(100)` again after reading the parquet file?

*Background*: in my actual application I write a lot of different datasets with carefully tuned partitions and I would like to restore these partitions without having to record individually for each dataframe how the partitions looked like when writing them to disk.

I am using Spark 2.3.0.

---

*Update*: same result for Spark 2.4.6 and 3.0.0

Comment: I have noticed the same recently in my code but when I ran the sparkjob I could actually observe that the frame had more than 4 partitions in the end. Have you had a look at the spark interface while the job was running? Might be interesting if you can observe the same.

Comment: @MeiSign I have checked in the SparkUI that there are four tasks running, and also when using foreachPartition, I can see that the function is called 4 times

Comment: Can tell why u want that? Catalyst optimization what not

Comment: @thebluephantom I have three long running (>20min) Spark programms A, B and C. C needs as input data the results of A and B. Due to hardware limitations, I can run only one job at a time. And the results of A have to be sent to downstream systems as soon as possible. That is why I store the results of A and B in parquet files and read them later in C. C runs faster if its input datasets are partitioned like they come out of A and B.

Comment: Ok, thx. I can get that on RDDs, but keep reading that with DFs its all under the hood, so a little confused.

Comment: so old habits like partitioning still need human insight and for good reason still

Comment: I met a similar problem. Do you have a solution for this problem now?

Comment: @for_stack No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I've solved it by writing a custom datasource. I extend `ParquetDataSourceV2` and the other classes and override `partitions` in `ParquetScan`. There I deleted the splitting code and just make one partition for each file. Files for empty partitions will be missing so I fill them in. (Sorry, I'm not at liberty to share the code.)

Comment: what about setting `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` so that it matches a file size? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: Yeah, if all the part files are the exact same size, you could do that. Otherwise `PartitionedFileUtil.splitFiles` will split some or `FilePartition.getFilePartitions` will merge some. (I think.)

Comment: **Some** difference in file sizes can be negotiated by adjusting `spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes`. With vast differences, you wouldn't want your partitions heavily skewed after read anyway, so its a mute point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have just open-sourced our solution to this problem. You can find it at https://github.com/lynxkite/lynxkite/blob/main/app/com/lynxanalytics/biggraph/partitioned_parquet/PartitionedParquet.scala. (It's part of a large AGPL application rather than a library. Sorry about that.)

You use it like this:

```scala
//re-read the parquet file into a dataframe and print the number of partitions
val readDf = spark.read
  .format(com.lynxanalytics.biggraph.partitioned_parquet.PartitionedParquet.format)
  .option("partitions", 100)
  .load("tmp/testds")
println("partitions after reading from disk: " + readDf.rdd.partitions.length)
```

Output:

```
partitions before writing to disk: 100
files written to disk: 202
partitions after reading from disk: 100
```

You need to provide the number of partitions as a parameter, because there's no way to tell from looking at the files. We see files from `part-00000` to `part-00099`. Maybe the original table had 100 partitions. Maybe it had 101 and the last one was empty.