# Write Spark Scala udf that will read parquet files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want manual control of proccess that devides data read to partitions. For example, suppose I have a DF

```
+---+---------------------+
|key|data                 |
+---+---------------------+
|k0 |[file0, file1, file2]|
|k1 |[file0, file3, file4]|
+---+---------------------+
```

And I have some `col_i, col_j` that I want to read from these files (in my case parquet) but I want to keep data in original partitions. So after udf call I expect to get something like

```
+---+------------------+------------------+
|key|             col_i|             col_j|
+---+------------------+------------------+
| k0|val_i_0_from_file0|val_j_0_from_file0|
| k0|val_i_1_from_file0|val_j_1_from_file0|
| k0|val_i_0_from_file1|val_j_0_from_file1|
| k0|val_i_0_from_file2|val_j_0_from_file2|
| k1|val_i_0_from_file0|val_j_0_from_file0|
| k1|val_i_1_from_file0|val_j_1_from_file0|
| k1|val_i_0_from_file3|val_j_0_from_file3|
| k1|val_i_0_from_file4|val_j_0_from_file4|
+---+------------------+------------------+
```

with all `k0` rows on same partition (same for `k1`).

Why such a question: Table with these files is not partitioned by `key` column but has it in its structure. I want to join by this column. **To avoid shuffle** on this key after reading I manually read metainfo about these parquet files, filter them based on other join side (small dataframe) and repartition these links by `key` before reading.

Comment: You cannot access the Spark session from inside the an udf, but you would need to access it in order to read parquet files. About the partitions: I have a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51090370/2129801).

Comment: Well that is not actually true, I can do that in python rdd like that (I have files in `s3`): `import pyarrow.parquet as pq; import s3fs; fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(...); for f in scene.files: parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(fs.open(f)); ... yield Row(...);`
and use such code in `flatMap` but that is not optimal.

Comment: And I know I can't use spark inside udf, but maybe there is a library or some code that works directly with `parquet` files. Maybe even some Reader inside `spark` project and I need to write few extra code to make that working

Comment: Yes, you are  right. I forgot about non-Spark ways to read parquet. Maybe [flatMap](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-flatmap-usage-with-example/) could help you?